# Downloading Facebook geo-targeted posts from API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, geotagging

Facebook's global pages can have regionally targeted content. Without admin access to the page, posts targeted to regions other than where the API key is registered don't show up in the API response.

For example, from a British account registered API key, it doesn't seem possible to download posts targeted to France on a global Facebook page.

Is there any way around this, other than registering keys in specific regions and using those to access the API?

Answer (score 2):

You can only access content via the API when acting on behalf of a user authorised to see that content.

If a Page post is restricted to be visible to users in a specific country only, the API will only return that post when you're using an access token from a user in that country.